# Simple JS function not working

Tags: javascript

I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working. It's a simple function to change the "add to cart" button on a radio button change, but any time I execute the function, it says it's not a function. What am I missing here?

```
 <h2>Select a Payment Option:</h2>

 <form  method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type="radio" name="addtocart" id="fullpay" value="66" onclick="fullpay();" /><h3 style="color: #f57e20;">Full Payment - <s>$119.80</s> $79.95</s></h3>

   <input type="radio" name="addtocart" id="payments" value="69" onclick="payments();" /><h3 style="color: #f57e20;">Payment plan - $26.65 / month for 3 months</h3>
   <hr/>
   <div id="cartbutton"></div>
 </form>
```

JS:

```
 window.onload = function(){

 function fullpay(){
    var cartbutton = document.getElementById("cartbutton");
    cartbutton.innerHTML = "<a href='/?add-to-cart=66' rel='nofollow' data-product_id='66' data-product_sku='' class='button add_to_cart_button'>Add to cart</a>";
}

 function payments(){
    var cartbutton = document.getElementById("cartbutton");
    cartbutton.innerHTML = "<a href='/?add-to-cart=69' rel='nofollow' data-product_id='69' data-product_sku='' class='button add_to_cart_button'>Add to cart</a>";
    }
 };
```

Comment: Put your functions outside of your window.onload and you're good to go. @Pointy already explained why it isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining your functions **inside** your "load" handler function. That means that the functions are private to that handler function, so they're not visible in the global context.

You could explicitly export the functions by assigning references to properties on the global object (`window`), or, probably better, use `.addEventListener()` inside your "load" handler to set up the event handling instead of old-school event attributes in your markup.

Comment: Oh of course. Thank you so much. I was driving myself crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Make you functions global:

```
window.onload = function(){
// functions here are not global
};

// functions here are global
 function fullpay(){
    var cartbutton = document.getElementById("cartbutton");
    cartbutton.innerHTML = "<a href='/?add-to-cart=66' rel='nofollow' data-product_id='66' data-product_sku='' class='button add_to_cart_button'>Add to cart</a>";
}

 function payments(){
    var cartbutton = document.getElementById("cartbutton");
    cartbutton.innerHTML = "<a href='/?add-to-cart=69' rel='nofollow' data-product_id='69' data-product_sku='' class='button add_to_cart_button'>Add to cart</a>";
    }
```